# Sumifs, but only on once for each set of matching values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am extracting sums from a table, and there is one thing I can't figure out how to do: I need to get the results only **once** no matter how many times there is a match.

For example, I need to sum the total of column C for all rows where A and B both match the values of current row, but I need to get the answer only ONCE, not on every row where they match, although it doesn't matter which instance it is (first, last, middle, etc.).

Sample Table:

```
1 | 100 | 4.0
1 | 100 | 7.3
1 | 200 | 9.5
2 | 100 | 4.7
2 | 200 | 9.0
2 | 100 | 9.1
2 | 100 | 7.4
```

I would want to get the results (assuming they showed at the first match):

```
11.3
 0.0
 9.5
21.2
 9.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

How do I do this?

Comment: starting at the second line just wrap it into this: `=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A2,B$1:B1,B2),"here comes your sumifs",0)`

Comment: why not use a pivottable?

Comment: @KS Sheon - because of the combination of how I need to use the data later, and my (limited) skill-set.

Comment: @Dirk Reichel - I'll give that a shot Monday.

Comment: @Dirk Reichel - the calculations come out multiple times, which is what I was trying to avoid, but I've got a solution now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this and it works:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2,$B$2:$B$8,B2)=COUNTIFS($A2:$A$8,A2,$B2:$B$8,B2),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8,A2,$B$2:$B$8,B2),0)
```

Comment: I'm not able to log in to my work computer at the moment, so I'll try this on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

regarding the comments:
oh true.... messed up the true/false part...

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A2,B$1:B1,B2),0,"here comes your sumifs")
```

so for your whole formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A2,B$1:B1,B2),0,SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2))
```

to get the solution always at the first line. ;)